# Constraint en Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, iphone

Hay alguna forma de hacer contenidos responsive sin usar Constraint?
Porque estoy realizando un lector rss y para que se adapte a todos los iphone tengo que poner constraints pero siempre que las uso me aparecen estos errores en la consola

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa26a6da110 UILabel:0x7fa26a6d8340'Construir una pista depor...'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa26a6d7620.topMargin + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa26a6da1b0 V:[UILabel:0x7fa26a6d8340'Construir una pista depor...']-(5)-[UILabel:0x7fa26a6d9030'Martes, 14 de Junio de 20...']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa26a6da2f0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa26a6d7620.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x7fa26a6d77c0'Son los anuncios que ha r...'.bottom + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa26a6da340 V:[UILabel:0x7fa26a6d9030'Martes, 14 de Junio de 20...']-(5)-[UILabel:0x7fa26a6d77c0'Son los anuncios que ha r...']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa26a6ed570 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa26a6d7620(44.5)]>"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de tres formas, usar las *constraints* sugeridas, configurarlas tu manualmente o conectar tu View a un ViewController y mediante código darle las distintas propiedades con un if por ejemplo a cada tamaño de pantalla.